# Overloading augmented assignment in c++ (return type)

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I am making an object that uses += operations. Should overload return reference to `*this` or should it just return `*this`?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @bath I was just about to close this question as a duplicate of the same one. I see that you reopened it. Do you disagree that it's a duplicate? Are you preparing to post an epic answer?

Comment: I reopened as the proposed duplicate was too broad for such a pointed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

There you can find *Canonical implementations*.

```
class X
{
 public:
  X& operator+=(const X& rhs) // compound assignment (does not need to be a member,
  {                           // but often is, to modify the private members)
    /* addition of rhs to *this takes place here */
    return *this; // return the result by reference
  }

  // friends defined inside class body are inline and are hidden from non-ADL lookup
  friend X operator+(X lhs,        // passing lhs by value helps optimize chained a+b+c
                     const X& rhs) // otherwise, both parameters may be const references
  {
    lhs += rhs; // reuse compound assignment
    return lhs; // return the result by value (uses move constructor)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `foo` and `bar` are instances of `Foo`.

If `+=` **didn't** return a reference, then the expression

`foo += bar += bar`

would be syntactically invalid which would be a departure from the built-in types (although it's interesting to note that the behaviour of such an expression for a built in type is undefined as `+=` is not a sequencing point for such types.).

Not returning a reference might also result in more uses of the copy constructor for `Foo`.

Quick answer: return a non-`const` reference.